# Get all items from collection where _id exists in array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and document-based DBs in general and still having a hard time wrapping my head around it all. I am trying to get all items from a collection where the _id field is equal to an array of other _id fields.

So if I had the following collections with items:

```
Collection "Parents"

Parent 1:
   Children:{
      Child 1: _id = 1,
      Child 2: _id = 2,
      Child 3: _id = 3
   }

Collection "Children"

Children 1: _id = 1,
Children 2: _id = 2,
Children 3: _id = 3,
Children 4: _id = 4
```

And I get Parent 1 like this:

```
var parent = this.GetParents().Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I query all Children from Children collection that are in the parent's Children array so the result would be:

```
Children 1: _id = 1,
Children 2: _id = 2,
Children 3: _id = 3,
```

Clarification:

To better illustrate what I need, consider this LINQ query:

```
var children = this.GetChildrenCollection().Find(c => parent.Children.Contains(c.ID));
```

I am looking for the MongoDB-Way of doing this (with FilterDefinitions etc.)